Why 3 setTimeout funcs were executed at the same time (as macrotasks)?
setTimeout is a macrotask right? And event loop executes only 1 macrotask in 1 "tick", as far as I understand. So, why does it look like these functions were executed in one "tick" of event loop. I mean, just in one 1000ms delay, not in chain of three 1000ms delays after each other.
setTimeout(() => console.log("First"), 1000)
setTimeout(() => console.log("Second"), 1000)
setTimeout(() => console.log("Third"), 1000)


There is no "chaining" of multiple setTimeout calls. You are instructing the browser to execute a function 1000 ms from now, and you are doing that three times. So this will execute those three functions, in (about) 1000 ms from now.

But I can't figure out in my head how it works within the concepts of macrotask and event loop. Are these setTimeouts macrotasks and they were complited in 3 ticks of event loop?

After the synchronous execution of your code ends, there will be three independent timers of 1 second each in the background. Once they all expire, the callback associated with each timer will be pushed on the callback / task queue.
Once the callbacks are in the task queue, event loop will push them on to the callstack one after the other, provided that the callstack is empty.
Only one task is processed in a single event loop tick and as there is no other code in the callstack, each task will be executed one after the other in each tick of the event loop.

All three functions are called about 1000ms from now, that means they start at about the same time. A way to make the logs 1000ms after one another is to put a setTimeout call inside another's callback (but there may be a concern of readability).

All of your setTimeouts are independent to eachother. They will be pushed to callback queue without waiting for the first ones to be executed.
